# How to set up an onTouchListener that changes an ImageView image resource?

Tags: java, android

I want to setup up an onTouchListener that changes an ImageViews image resource on ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN. Here is my code:

```
    // Setup a basic upDownListener that registers UP and DOWN actions and changes the
    // view image resource accordingly
    View.OnTouchListener upDownListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Button was pressed, change button background
                v.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white_pressure);
                return true;
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Button was released, reset button background
                v.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    };
```

This code does not compile because View does not have the method setImageResource, only ImageView. But how do I tell the listener that an ImageView is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the incoming `View` to an `ImageView`.

Sample code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white_pressure);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: By the way, can I add custom parameters to my onTouchListener somehow? I want the drawable resource to be customizable.

Comment: Not with the `onTouchListener` interface. My advice is simple; make your drawables resources global variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
View.OnTouchListener upDownListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView v = (ImageView) v;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Button was pressed, change button background
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white_pressure);
            return true;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Button was released, reset button background
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

};
```

Comment: Chaning it to ImageView still doesn't work, eclipse still says that the method setImageResource(int) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Did you use your imageView variable instead of the View variable that is sent in the onTouch method? So like my example above:  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white_pressure);  
If that doesn't work, cast the View to an ImageView.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I just cast the view v to an imageview before i do anything with it inside onTouch()

Comment: I think you are making it more difficult for yourself than it actually is. If you are clicking on an ImageView, try as I said above... and use your imageView variable to call the setImageResource method on! So imageView.setImageResource()  and NOT  view.setImageResource(), because indeed, that method cannot be called on a View object.

Comment: Im creating a custom onTouchListener, not one for a specific view so I need to reference the View v

Comment: @Jules: You are making it more difficult than necessary. The only thing he need to do is to cast from `View` to `ImageView`. No need for the duplicated code that it'll be if he should define same listener in many `ImageView`s.

Comment: @soren.qvist: Yes, that is the way to go.

Comment: @Pompe de velo haha, I suggested that already 10 minutes ago if you read the comments. But there is really no need in casting the view if you implement the OnTouchListener properly. Casting the View makes no sense in this case. It's just a work-around.

Comment: Ok, should have told that before, soren. Then it does make sense.. :)  Edited my post.

Comment: @Jules: Casting makes perfectly sense here. He creates a custom `onTouchListener` that will be used for an unknown number of `ImageView`s. Defining a new `onTouchListener` works, but it will lead to duplicated code.

Comment: Saw you accepted an answer that came in 15 minutes after I already gave you the same answer right here... zzzZZzzz

Comment: Sorry Jules, you're right I should have specified that in my post.